# Troubleshooting network connection with Ubuntu in VirtualBox (OS X)

Tags: macos, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am setting up Ubuntu Server 14.04 using VirtualBox on an iMac running OS X Yosemite.  I know very little about setting up network information, and cannot get Ubuntu connected to the internet (though I can ssh into the server).  I would like to use a bridged adapter with a static IP.  Below I have a few piece of helpful (I hope) information.  Let me know if I should include something else.

---

My current `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.1.251
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

---

The results of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:13:0c:ba  
          inet addr:10.0.1.251  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe13:cba/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:444:c000:33f4:a00:27ff:fe13:cba/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:920 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:539 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:84566 (84.5 KB)  TX bytes:75947 (75.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5752 (5.7 KB)  TX bytes:5752 (5.7 KB)
```

---

Results of an attempt to ping 8.8.8.8:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.1.251 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.1.251 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.1.251 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.1.251 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.1.251 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.1.251 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 6999ms
pipe 4
```

If I try to ping any other website, it just hangs there until it eventually says, `ping: unknown host www.google.com` (or whatever website I tried).

---

What is causing this problem, and what can I do to fix it?  Let me know if I can include other helpful information.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of 'netstat -rn' ? do you have default gateway entry there? If so, can you ping the default gateway?